# Why are my TextViews null?

Tags: java, android, methods, widget

I want if the user enters an invalid number, two `TextView`s should change their texts.
I looked up and checked if I got more than one `TextView` with the same id and the ruesult was that each id from my  `TextView`s are unique.

Everytime I force my error with entering an invalid number my app crashes. If i start the app in debug and marked my two "problematic codes". The result was both `TextView`s were `null`.
I don't know why this happens because the id's are unique and I don't  change my current layout.

My java code:

```
public void checkingInput(View view) {
    TextView eKnowledge  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enterKnowledge);

    try{
        int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(eKnowledge.getText().toString());
        _knowledge = KnowledgeLevel.fromUserInput(inputNumber);
        test();
        hideKeyboard(view);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        errorKnowledge();
        hideKeyboard(view);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public void test() {
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_nur_einmal_benutzt_hoff_ich);
    switch(_knowledge) {
        case NOOB:
            test.setText("ENUM = NOOB");
            break;
        case BEGINNER:
            test.setText("ENUM = BEGINNER");
            break;
        case ADVANCED:
            test.setText("ENUM = ADV");
            break;
        case PRO:
            test.setText("ENUM = PRO");
            break;
        case GRANDMASTER:
            test.setText("ENUM = GM");
            break;
        case ERROR:
            errorKnowledge();
            break;
        case FAIL:
            test.setText("FEHLER!");
            break;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public void errorKnowledge(){
    TextView hKnowledge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testWissenstandHeader);
    TextView tKnowledge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testWissenstandText);

    /* da ist der fehler ... einmal mit dem debugger durch zeigt es doch direkt: hKnowledge und tKnowledge sind null, daher die NullPointerException */

    hKnowledge.getResources().getString(R.string.FehlerGefunden);
    hKnowledge.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
    tKnowledge.getResources().getString(R.string.FehlerText1);
    tKnowledge.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}

private enum KnowledgeLevel {
    FAIL, ERROR, NOOB, BEGINNER, ADVANCED, PRO, GRANDMASTER;

    static KnowledgeLevel fromUserInput(final int input)
    {
        if (input >= 11 || input <= -1) {
            return ERROR;
        }
        else if (input == 10) {
            return GRANDMASTER;
        }
        else if (input >= 7) {
            return PRO;
        }
        else if (input >= 4) {
            return ADVANCED;
        }
        else if (input >= 1 ) {
            return BEGINNER;
        }
        else if (input == 0) {
            return NOOB;
        }
        return FAIL;
    }
}
```

And my XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testWissenstandHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Bla"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#511613"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/kastenKnowledge"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/kastenKnowledge"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/kastenKnowledge"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/kastenKnowledge"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testWissenstandText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text='BlaBla'
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#E0E0E0"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/testWissenstandHeader"/>
```

I researched a bit and the only solution I found on stackoverflow.com was that I need to use `setContentView();` but I've got two problems with that:
1. Why should I use that if I don't chnage my layout?
2. I tried it and my app didn't crash BUT my texts didn't change. (`setContentView();` were used before `setText();"` is used)

Here's my whole errorreport (no debug prozess):

```
08-10 00:14:53.580 2774-2774/com.example.alexander.hashtagnevereverbuggy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.alexander.hashtagnevereverbuggy, PID: 2774
                                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.widget.TextView.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at com.example.alexander.hashtagnevereverbuggy.MainActivity.errorKnowledge(MainActivity.java:112)
                                                                                           at com.example.alexander.hashtagnevereverbuggy.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:97)
                                                                                           at com.example.alexander.hashtagnevereverbuggy.MainActivity.checkingInput(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

EDIT:

```
package com.example.alexander.hashtagnevereverbuggy;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import java.util.Map;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Heroes {

private KnowledgeLevel _knowledge = KnowledgeLevel.NOOB;

private static FragmentManager _fragmentManager;

private enum WerteTextFelder {
    TITLE,TYP, DAMAGE, LADUNG, KUGELN, NACHLADEDAUER, HEILUNG, HEADSHOT, WIRKUNGSDAUER, EXTRAEFFEKT, BESONDERHEIT
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.AppID));

    _fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    Button testButtonAnfang = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AnfangsButton);
    testButtonAnfang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.testwissenstand);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public void checkingInput(View view) {
    TextView eKnowledge  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enterKnowledge);

    try{
        int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(eKnowledge.getText().toString());
        _knowledge = KnowledgeLevel.fromUserInput(inputNumber);
        test();
        hideKeyboard(view);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        errorKnowledge();
        hideKeyboard(view);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public void test() {
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_nur_einmal_benutzt_hoff_ich);
    switch(_knowledge) {
        case NOOB:
            test.setText("ENUM = NOOB");
            break;
        case BEGINNER:
            test.setText("ENUM = BEGINNER");
            break;
        case ADVANCED:
            test.setText("ENUM = ADV");
            break;
        case PRO:
            test.setText("ENUM = PRO");
            break;
        case GRANDMASTER:
            test.setText("ENUM = GM");
            break;
        case ERROR:
            errorKnowledge();
            break;
        case FAIL:
            test.setText("FEHLER!");
            break;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public void errorKnowledge(){
    TextView hKnowledge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testWissenstandHeader);
    TextView tKnowledge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testWissenstandText);

    /* da ist der fehler ... einmal mit dem debugger durch zeigt es doch direkt: hKnowledge und tKnowledge sind null, daher die NullPointerException */

    hKnowledge.getResources().getString(R.string.FehlerGefunden);
    hKnowledge.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
    tKnowledge.getResources().getString(R.string.FehlerText1);
    tKnowledge.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}

private enum KnowledgeLevel {
    FAIL, ERROR, NOOB, BEGINNER, ADVANCED, PRO, GRANDMASTER;

    static KnowledgeLevel fromUserInput(final int input)
    {
        if (input >= 11 || input <= -1) {
            return ERROR;
        }
        else if (input == 10) {
            return GRANDMASTER;
        }
        else if (input >= 7) {
            return PRO;
        }
        else if (input >= 4) {
            return ADVANCED;
        }
        else if (input >= 1 ) {
            return BEGINNER;
        }
        else if (input == 0) {
            return NOOB;
        }
        return FAIL;
    }
}

public static void addTransaction(Fragment fragment, String tag){
    if (_fragmentManager != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = _fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

private void hideKeyboard(View view){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

private class geileListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Hero hero;

    private geileListener (Hero hero) {
        this.hero = hero;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setContentView(hero.getHeroLayout());
    }
}

private void advertisment() {
    /*Notwendig um advertisment im showlock darzustellen*/
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public void showPreview (Hero hero) {
    setContentView(hero.getPreviewLayout());
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_Preview);
    button.setImageResource(hero.getPreviewImage());
    button.setOnClickListener(new geileListener(hero));
    advertisment();
}

private Map<WerteTextFelder, TextView> getWerteTextFelder() {
    setContentView(R.layout.werte);
    Map<WerteTextFelder, TextView> map  = new HashMap<>();


    TextView Titel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Überschrift);
    TextView Typ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Werte_0);
    TextView Damage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_1);
    TextView Ladung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_2);
    TextView Kugeln = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_3);
    TextView Nachladedauer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_4);
    TextView Heilung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_5);
    TextView Headshot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_6);
    TextView Wirkungsdauer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_7);
    TextView ExtraEffekt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_8);
    TextView wert9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wert_9);

    map.put(WerteTextFelder.TITLE, Titel);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.TYP, Typ);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.DAMAGE, Damage);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.LADUNG, Ladung);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.KUGELN, Kugeln);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.NACHLADEDAUER, Nachladedauer);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.HEILUNG, Heilung);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.HEADSHOT, Headshot);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.WIRKUNGSDAUER, Wirkungsdauer);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.EXTRAEFFEKT, ExtraEffekt);
    map.put(WerteTextFelder.BESONDERHEIT, wert9);

    return map;
}
```

Everything else (abput 4k Lines of code) arent important

Comment: Can you publish the whole class? I'd like to understand when the errorKnowledge method is called, and if you've run a setContentView in the onCreate method.

Comment: from your log it's saying you have a problem on "onClick"

Comment: @instantiator I updated my code. There you go

Comment: @Salman500 Idk why, because I use my `checkingInput` method and my button got this `onClick` method. I don't know why there should be any problem

Comment: What invalid num. are you trying to input?

Comment: @iann -1 or lower, 11 or higher

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()`, you have to to call `setContentView(R.layout.whateveryourxml)`. After that, but still tracing back to your onCreate, you may call `errorKnowledge()`. This should make sure that neither TextView is null.

Comment: I updated my question, I don't think I need to do sth in my `onCreate();` method.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: Just to clarify, you *do* have to call the setContentView method during onCreate, or your TextViews will resolve to null. Assuming you've done that - as in the code you posted - read on!]

These lines of code don't seem right to me. They don't look as if they will do anything:

```
hKnowledge.getResources().getString(R.string.FehlerGefunden);
hKnowledge.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
tKnowledge.getResources().getString(R.string.FehlerText1);
tKnowledge.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
```

The reason you're seeing no effect is that these are get statements that return some values, but then you don't actually use those values to *do* anything.

I feel like what you actually want to say is this:

```
hKnowledge.setText(R.string.FehlerGefunden);
hKnowledge.setTextColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
tKnowledge.setText(R.string.FehlerText1);
tKnowledge.setTextColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
```

I'd also recommend that you spend some time in your onCreate method doing all the findView work, so that you don't need to do it again and again later. (It's also a little clearer and saves you quite a bit of boilerplate java.)

You can define your various TextView elements (etc.) as private members for the class, so - as an example, just for the 2 TextViews we're already talking about:

```
private TextView hKnowledge;
private TextView tKnowledge;
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  hKnowledge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testWissenstandHeader);
  tKnowledge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testWissenstandText);
  ...
}
```

Having done this, you can then refer to the two TextViews from anywhere else in your class just as their members: hKnowledge and tKnowledge;

Comment: A question to your edit:  My "start" layout is "activity_main" and there is a button which changes the contentView to "testwissenstand". So why do I need to do that in my `onCreate` method?
If I use more than one `setContentView`, I thought it will only use the last one

Comment: It's possible I suppose, although it seems the recommended way to change layouts around dynamically is with Fragments. Fragments have complex lifecycles though so I'd recommend reading up on them.

You could inflate the views manually yourself, and then set your various buttons etc. on the appropriate view, ie. if you create a view `view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);` then you can find your buttons in it like this `button1 = view1.findViewById(R.id.button_1);` and then you can `setContentView(view1);` (or to any other view) as you prefer.