# How can I make a video clickable if its finished or infinite?

Tags: java, android, video

I want to have two features in my android app.

First feature:
I want that if I press a button, my layout should change (`setContentView();`) and **after** it's finished the user can click on it and something happens, but if the user clicks on the viedo **before** it's finished nothing should happen.

Second feature:
I want a gif/vidoe beeing in an inifite loop, for example a gif/video showing a new animation in games, and the user can click on it so something happens **but** the video/gif shouldn't be stopped and it shouldn't pop up any media options like "play" "pause" "skip" etc..

I researched a bit but I didn't find any soloutions fiting to my problem/whish.
If you need any extra code or information tell me.
It should be written in java (MainActivity.java), that'd be great!

Comment: You can attach click handlers to video elements can't you?

Comment: @Carcigenicate To be honest, I've seen many people doing something with "handlers" but I don't know what they do or how they work, as I said, I'm kinda new to programming.

Comment: Understanding handlers is extremely important. Honestly, I misread this as a java*script* question, not a *java* one. It's still important in Java though. Handlers are how you deal with problems like this. The handler will run some code when an event (like clicking) happens. If you're new to programming, you may want to take a step back (no offense). Make sure you're not trying to progress so fast that you're hindering your learning.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Dont get me wrong, I love learning with real code, it doesnt have to be the complete code but just reading isnt the way I learning that much. With real code I follow the code. I guess you got my point

Comment: I just mentioned that because I fear that people are trying to jump right into writing apps too quickly. I still think one of the best decisions I ever made when learning was to start slow. I only wrote console programs for my first couple years, which pretty much forces you to have the basics down. If you're learning fine, then that's good. I just thought I'd share that tip. It's not uncommon to see people here trying to write full Android apps when they don't even understand how variable scoping works.

Comment: Well my main school project is IT, and I'm already (letÄ's say "level" as comparing) level 10, but my other classmates are level 2 and my teacher is level 15, and my buddy teaching me coding does this as this work. So he forces me to slow down because he teaches only things, beeing basic and only does further if I got it, so if I try coding myself he always looks it up and correct it with me. (I guess you got my again ^^") If I say to him "can u explain this to me" he explains it without question it to me. So if you have any codes or "easy" sites for me, go ahead. Sry for the long text.

Comment: Np. Again, if the learning style works for you, then good. But back to your main question, to react to clicks, you attach/register an event handler with the button you want to react to. I don't have any guides off the top of my head to suggest, but everything Android is fairly well documented, and I suspect many people have written guides on the topic. Understanding event handlers is also vital if you ever want to do any web programming, since Javascript makes heavy use of handlers.

Comment: Well, I never "met" javascript and my buddy says it's aweful to code. So atm I only use java, classes, enum, interfaces but everything is still coded in java.
And I only want to code android apps, not websites ^^"

Comment: Javascript isn't the greatest language, but it's very useable. It's loose though so it doesn't give you as much protection from doing dumb things, and has weird things that will snag you every once in awhile, like how `this` works. You can always use a language that compiles to JS though, so you dont usually need to use JS directly.

Comment: OK, got it. If you want you can see me other question, mybe you have a solution ^^"
[There you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602527/why-are-my-textviews-null)